# Having issue passing data from Form in Paypal-rest-sdk using Node

Tags: node.js, paypal

This is my code.  Can you please tell me how to pass the form field in PayPal API?

The Issue I am getting here is when I am trying to pass Dummy data mine API is working fine but when I am trying to pass Fields from mine Form its not working. I have `console.log` and check it I am getting data on this API.

```
router.post('/checkout/pay',function(req,res){
    var title="req.body.title";
    var price="req.body.price";
    var qty=1

  var create_payment_json = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/success",
            "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "item_list": {
                "items": [{
                    "name": title,
                    "sku": "001",
                    "price":price ,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "quantity": 1,
                }]
            },
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": price,
            },
            "description": "This is the payment description."
        }]
    };

    function handleError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        handleError(error);
    } else {
            console.log("Create Payment Response");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
            res.send('test');
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Stop putting all of your text in bold.

Comment: Calm down. YELLING does not help your question. **Excessive** use of **BOLD** is not constructive.

Comment: Additionally, how is this different from you other question: [I cant req.params.anything from my from using NODE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51044012/691711)

Comment: in this form I get the data from console.log but was not able to pass it through Paypal api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The issue was with my form I was trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBxz8.png)

I was trying to do something like this

**value=$nbsp;"<%= parseFloat(total).toFixed(2) %>"**

Instead of it should be like this

**value="<%= parseFloat(total).toFixed(2) %>"**

I forget that their would be a validation in Paypal Service